# JSON Response to PDF in Nativescript

Tags: json, pdf, nativescript

I want to perform a PDF download functionality in nativescript. Is there any way by which we can convert JSON response to PDF file in nativescript.

Comment: if you get sent the PDF in base64 over JSON, you can convert it out and use fs (file-system) to save it

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Sorry its not clear

Comment: are you getting the pdf from your own server?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : No I am not getting pdf from server. i am getting a JSON response.Using the response , I need to create PDF

Comment: but is it a server you own/have access to or another online server?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : I dont have access to the online server.

Comment: ok, do you get the PDF in the JSON data as a base64 string?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : suppose I get the json as [{'name':'abc','text':hello},{name:'cde','text':'hi'}]. I need to create a pdf with name and text as columns of table